# Fill Color gap between Navigation bar and Carrier details in Swift

Tags: swift, ios8, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

Attached screen shot shows clear gap between carrier details and Navigation bar, How to fill the same red color and change the text of carrier details , time displayed to white color ?

[image: Carrier details are displayed in white background , need to change that to navigation bar color and also change text color from black to white]

Comment: white background where carrier , Verizon , Time  displayed should also have background as navigation bar.

Comment: Found the solution , need to add Navigation Controller which should be tied to View Controller, then the result will be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to add Navigation Controller which should be tied to View Controller, then the result will be achieved.